# Evaluating a string without using eval()

Tags: javascript, eval

I am creating a 'generic' web scraper the would **scrape** any page having a list of entries. I would like to drive from the config the tags that it should extract.

Example with the following config:

```
{ 
    name : "price",
    valueJQueryExpression : ".mt9 > .mt7.b"
},
```

... I'm parsing the following way:

```
const $ = require('cheerio');
let jquery = getQuery("price");
let keys = $(jquery);
```

However, I have more tricky parsers to handle, eg. that one:

```
let location = $('.mt9 > .b', html).not('.mt5').not('.mt7').text().trim()
```

In such case I thought using an `eval()` and pass the full expression in the config. However this is not recommended due to safety issues.

Would you have any recommendation on handling this differently?

Comment: try using xpath instead of css selector, you won't have to chain jQuery functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`:not` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) here. Try the following:

```
$('.mt9 > .b:not(.mt5):not(.mt7)', html).text().trim()
```

It is similar to jQuery, where the selector specified inside `:not()` will be used to exclude elements from the matches.

You can see it in action below:

```css
.mt9 > .b:not(.mt5):not(.mt7) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mt9">
  <div class="b">This should be red</div>
  <div class="b mt7">This should not be red</div>
  <div class="b mt5">This should not be red</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var command = 'console.log("Hello")';
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.textContent = command;
document.head.appendChild(s);
```